# 'drawBox' does not name a type error

Tags: c++, sdl

I keep having some weird errors while coding on C++ using SDL as my graphics library.

Today, I was starting to develop a game I wanna make, and suddenly a encountered a quite strange error.

```
#ifndef CREATURE_H_
#define CREATURE_H_




#include "SDL/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

class Creature 
{
    private:




        SDL_Rect drawBox;
        drawBox.x;
        drawBox.y;
        drawBox.h;
        drawBox.w;

        SDL_Surface *sprite;

    public:
        void spawn (SDL_Rect drawBox,SDL_Surface* screen);
        bool isTouching (class object);
        bool isAlive ();
        void move (int x,int y);
        bool isFalling ();
        void setSprite ();

};



#endif
```

That's my creature.h header file, and the creature.cpp is empty (it can compile but it wont do anything interesting). So, I can see that SDL_Rect is a struct and all that,but then why won't the SDL_Rect's name be treated as a variable name when it is? See ya guys, and peace.

Comment: The post got undervoted randomly, or for a reason I don't know, can someone explain?

Comment: `drawBox.x;` isn't a valid expression in a class definition.  It wouldn't do anything useful anywhere it was a legal expression either.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RetiredNinja have read everywhere that's the way to initialize the members of SDL_Rect, and that's basically what I'm trying to do, prepare the Creature class to be used. It's like do <code> int lol; </code> . Why are you doing it? To keep <code> lol </code> ready I guess.

Comment: Remove the `drawBox.x; drawBox.y; ...` from the class.

Comment: @self. Then drawBox's members won't be initialized, and that's exactly what I don't want.

Comment: It would appear that everything you read is wrong. :)  In the class definition you are describing what the class contains, so `SDL_Rect drawBox;` is fine, it says that any instance of the class contains a rect with that name.  If you want to change the value of that variable you need to do it on an instance of the class, like perhaps in the constructor.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Write an answer would you please...

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok, sir. Imma test it, anyway, post it as an answer so I can close the question if it works.

Comment: Congrats on learning programming, while you wait for an answer you might search for a simple *c++ class tutorial*.

Comment: @self. I do know C++ quite good, but I'm starting on classes, but anyway, PROBLEM FIXED!! Waiting for the answer to close question.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems If you solved the issue, you are actually encouraged to answer your own question. It will get upvoted.

Comment: I see. I'll do that now.

Comment: @self. I have to wait as I have reputation  < 10... So you post the answer as RetiredNinja won't.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the members from drawBox from the class declaration will do, if I wished to change the values of those members, I would have to create a Creature object. And that's about. Thanks everyone.